# error while connecting mariadb with c : undefined reference to `mysql_init@4'

Tags: mysql, c, mariadb

I am trying to connect to mariadb database using c program. Initially it was showing error for #include <mysql.h> as no such file or directory.
But after including directory name, that problem is solved now, but it is showing another error.

Following is the code I was trying to run:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
// #include "C:/Program Files/MariaDB 10.11/include/mysql/my_global.h"
#include "mysql/mysql.h"


int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

   // Initialize Connection
   MYSQL *conn;
   if (!(conn = mysql_init(0)))
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "unable to initialize connection struct\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   // Connect to the database
   if (!mysql_real_connect(
         conn,                 // Connection
         "mariadb.example.net", // Host
         "db_user",            // User account
         "db_user_password",   // User password
         "test",               // Default database
         3306,                 // Port number
         NULL,                 // Path to socket file
         0                     // Additional options
      ));
   {
      // Report the failed-connection error & close the handle
      fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting to Server: %s\n", mysql_error(conn));
      mysql_close(conn);
      exit(1);
   }

   // Use the Connection
   // ...

   // Close the Connection
   mysql_close(conn);

   return 0;
}
```

I am getting following error in output:

```
PS C:\Dev\Win> gcc Db_con.c -o Db_con
C:\Users\hajos\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGZ2Rhz.o:Db_con.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `mysql_init@4'
C:\Users\hajos\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGZ2Rhz.o:Db_con.c:(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect@32'
C:\Users\hajos\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGZ2Rhz.o:Db_con.c:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `mysql_error@4'
C:\Users\hajos\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGZ2Rhz.o:Db_con.c:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to `mysql_close@4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone explain what is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Did you add the library for MySQL functions? What is your linker ommand?

Comment: I have included mysql.h file in my working directory.
But I am not aware of what linker command is.

Comment: The header only tells the compiler that there are some functions out there and how the parameter lists look etc. You must provide the library that contains the definitions for those functions when you compile and link your code. What command do you use to build your program?

Comment: You should not put library headers into your local working directory. Instead place them in the default include folder and add extra folders to your compiler command if needed.

Comment: I was using the following command:
gcc test.c -o test.c
gcc test.c -o test.c -I "C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C 64-bit\include"

Comment: Please add the command to the question

Comment: Yes I have added the command in the question.

Comment: Please dont get confused with file names test.c and Db_con.c. Both of these are the same files, I needed to rename the file name for some reason.

Comment: Why is the command in your comment completely different from the command you added to the question? Both commands do not include any libraries. See the existing answer.

Comment: Yes the commands are different because I renamed my file. And I don't know which libraries are required to include in the command.

Answer (score 0):

You have to link against the MariaDB Connector/C libraries.

From [MariaDB Connector/C documentation](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-c/wiki/build_client_apps):

**Linking your application against MariaDB Connector/C
Windows**

For static linking the library libmariadb.lib is required, for dynamic linking use libmariadb.dll. Using the MSI installer, these libraries can be found in the lib directory of your MariaDB Connector/C installation.

Unless you use the experimental plugin remote_io (which requires the curl library) there are no dependencies to other libraries than the Windows system libraries.